# How to make a .net dll stored procedure using VS2010 and SQL Server 2005?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-2005

Does anyone have a tutorial on how to first make .net dll solution in VS2010 that will work for SQL Server 2005?

I heard they have a special solution but I am not sure which one it is. I am trying to write what I think they call an extended stored procedure.

Then a tutorial on how to actually right these extended stored procedures would be nice too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out:

- [SQL SERVER – Introduction to CLR – Simple Example of CLR Stored Procedure](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/19/sql-server-introduction-to-clr-simple-example-of-clr-stored-procedure/)
- [SQL CLR and using .NET assemblies in SQL Server](http://www.learnitfirst.com/Course/157/Video/1900/SQL-CLR-and-NET-Assemblies.aspx) (sample video)

or the site dedicated to the SQL CLR:

- [Using CLR in SQL Server 2005/2008](http://www.sqlclr.net/)

For those projects, you need to be careful to use CLR 2.0 (or thus: .NET 2.0 / 3.0 / 3.5 / 3.5 SP1) as your target CLR, since SQL Server 2005 (and 2008 and 2008 R2) only contain the CLR 2.0 (nothing newer - won't work with .NET 4 / CLR 4.0).

Comment: Then why does that guy use 3.5 in the first link you gave?

Comment: Hmm that did not take long to run into trouble. I made it to step one and get this when I try to create a server project. Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlServerCs, Version 3.5.1.0, Culture=neutrail, PublicKeyToke=89845dcd908080cc91'
or one of it dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: @chobo2: .NET 3.5 is using the CLR 2.0

Comment: Ok now that I can make a new server project I ran into the problem of not having one of the dialogs comeup. I don't get a dialog like he does in step 2: Either choose from existing database connection as reference or click on Add New Reference. In my example I have selected Add New Reference.